# How to load a referenced assembly within another referenced assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a scenario where my client is a `WPF` App let's say `W` , There are 3 assemblies say `A`, `B`,`C` which are not to be exposed to `W` , hence the 3 assemblies are referenced in a concrete factory , say `F` which creates the required instance and provides to `W`.

I am using reflection in `F` to generate the 3 objects.

Below is the code

```
return (IClass)Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.Load("A").GetType("A.AClass"), 
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, null, null);
```

The code works if I reference `A` in `W` , but doesn't work (`System.IO.FileNotFound Exception`) when `A` is referenced in `F` (I cross checked with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()` and `A` is not loaded).

I read that an `Assembly` may not be loaded if it is not required. But how does my `WPF` client then load the assembly. If this is the expected behavior , I would go with finding the current `Directory` path and appending `A.dll` to it.
Any thoughts around ?

Comment: Have you tried to use [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) handler?

Comment: Isn't this a fallback technique , I mean would I be able to actually get the original required assembly?

Comment: as far as I understand, you know this required assembly, so you can provide it via `Assembly.LoadFrom`

Comment: I suspect the files are not getting copied to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` when the solution is built.

Comment: I'd agree with Troy - I use a post build event to copy to the .dll's while debugging, and then include it as primary output for the setup build.  (i.e. you if you use a setup project the post build event doesn't copy the .dll's to the basedirectory, you need it's primary output included in the setup project).

Comment: @TroyPalacino: I think you're pointing out might be correct , since Im using in debug\release mode ,I'd face this issue . I'll confirm the results running the exe and then you can put down the answer.

Comment: Thanks , manually placing the dll does work , In deployment , I'll be having the DLLs along with the executables so shouldn't face this issue then. Could you post the answer , I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the files are not getting copied to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` when the solution is built. Without a reference you would need to manually ensure the required DLLs are being copied to the right location.

See BasconSah comment above for a suggestion.